# What is the price difference between the two companies?

Tags: finance

> Fireside Shop offers chimney caps for 120 dollars less trade discounts of 25/10. The same chimney cap is being offered at Builder's Supply for $111 less than the trade discounts of 25/5. What is the price difference between the two companies?

Please give some hints to this question. I'm not able to understand the phrase

> 120 dollars less trade discounts of 25/10.

Thank you :->

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have two consecutive discounts, where the discount rates are $25\%=0.25$ and $10\%=0.1$. After the two discounts the price $P$ reduces to $P\cdot (1-0.25)\cdot (1-0.1)=P\cdot 0.75\cdot 0.9=\frac{27}{40}\cdot P$.

*Hint:* Rounded to the nearest cent the price difference between the two companies is 1.91 dollars.